# Is there an (open source) VCS that can work with a whitelist instead of a blacklist?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, mercurial, cvs

I'm looking for an open source version control system that can be configured to track only a small number of individual files spread around the filesystem. Something like the opposite of .gitignore .

The use case is keeping track of changes that I make after installing an OS. Many of the changes are outside /etc, so I cannot just have /etc under revision control. And having / under revision control seemed very slow with git.

It seems that I can use a .gitignore as follows. To track, say, /usr/share/terminator/terminator :

```
*
!/usr
/usr/*
!/usr/share
/usr/share/*
!/usr/share/terminator
/use/share/terminator/*
!/usr/share/terminator/terminator
```

But this seems a bit clumsy (even if I were to auto-generate the .gitignore). Is there a better way (or a more appropriate version control system for this)?

Comment: Use a configuration management tool like Puppet.

Comment: Interesting, I'll try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use another work around for this with git. Note that git continues tracking a file even if it is in ignore rules, once it is already being tracked. So, assuming that you do not want to track new files very often,

1. Add all the files that you actually want to track

   ```
   git add file1 file2 dir1/file3 dir1/file4 dir1/dir2/file5 dir2
   ```
2. Commit these files using

   ```
   git commit -m "msg"
   ```
3. Add an ignore rule to your `.gitignore` to ignore all other files

   ```
   echo "*" > .gitignore
   ```
4. Now if you make changes to any of the existing files, they will show up in `git status`, `git diff` and so on. You can add them using `git add filename` and operate upon them normally.
5. To add a new file next time onwards, you need to use `-f`

   ```
   git add -f new_file1 
   git commit -m "msg"
   ```

Comment: And he has his repository in the root directory of the filesystem?

Comment: @AndrewC I assume you mean to ask about what happens if there are repositories within any of the subdirectory? Well, in this repository, each of those subfolder's repositories are ignored. And in each of those subfolder repository, git will note be able to detect the presence of this repository - git looks for the first `.git` folder it can find upwards the chain of parent directories.

Comment: @AndrewC Hmm I've been in such a situation before, when I was fiddling around and had to save some nginx and apache configurations to git for future references, though I did delete the local copy once I was done. I guess this should be avoided in general, but it does have its benefits in the short term :)

Comment: @AndrewC What if the repository is elsewhere, using git --work-tree / --git-dir /path/to/.git ?

Comment: the issue isn't where the git-dir is, it's with having the work-tree start at /